# In what order should I develop my N-Tier applicaition?

Tags: architecture, tdd, agile, n-tier-architecture, methodology

The problem, a team of developers getting an assignment to create big project from scratch, after considering pros and cons of some architectures, they decided to go for N-Tier architecture.
For an easy example, lets go for 3 Tier (as a very general and commun one).

Assuming they are working in agile development methodology, what would be the best order to do it?

I thought of 3 ways of doing it, and I can't really explain myself why one is better then the other:

1. Start with the DB, then Buisness, then Service, then Presentaition.
2. Build a fake Buisness Layer (Mock) and leave the DB to more advanced iteraition, then, after we have a fake working buisness layer, building a working Service layer on top of it (test it and make it perfect) and only then, get back to the DB and Buisness.
3. Build each use case from bottom up (DB -> Buisness -> Service -> Presentaition)

option 3 seems to me like the most agile way of doing it.
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134094/developing-n-tier-app-in-what-direction) question that talks about it, but I couldn't find strong enough answer for me.

Thanks ahead for your help!

Answer (score 1):

An agile approach is typically to try and get working software as early as possible so that you can receive feedback.

That would suggest the 3rd option is the best one: thin slices through the tiers to get working features as quickly as possible.

It would still be worth considering the use of mocks during the build process. You may find that helps to balance the workload if you have specialist developers (i.e. database developer, front-end developer, etc.).

For example:

- Select a high priority feature to work on
- Quickly mock some aspects of it, so that specialist developers on the various tiers can work without dependency on each other
- Build a thin slice through all the tiers, swapping out the mocks as each bit of code falls into place